# How to parse Solr's autoComplete results in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr, autocomplete

I was trying to implement Solr's Autocomplete function by using AJAX to retrieve possible suggestions, I have successfully retrieved the data but cannot parse the result. The code `data.response.docs` within 'success()' function does not work. The details can be seen below:

```
var term = $("#q").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/suggest',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          'q': term,
          'wt': 'json'
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
           //.....
        },
        error: function(ex) {
           alert("Error occurs during autocomplete. Please retry later.");
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf'
    });
```

Comment: can u post the result and wt the error is comming

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing? What is the content of data.response.docs before you do that? Does `data ` contain what you expect it to contain?

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 Hi, thank you for the reply. I just found the error was caused by 'response' field. Actually, when using autocomplete function in Solr, the retrieved data does not contain 'response' nor 'docs' field, that's why my code does not work. After changing the field now my code works fine.

Comment: @MatsLindh I followed a tutorial regarding autocomplete online, that's why I used those two functions... I checked the content of returned data and find out that the 'response' and 'docs' fields are not included in it, that's the reason my code does not work. Now it's working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After checking the returned data I found that the returned structure does not contain 'response' nor 'docs' field likes Solr's ordinary search function, that's the reason why my code `data.response.docs` does not work. Now the problem has been solved.